# connecting to xpack enabled elasticsearch 5.x via spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot

I am trying to use elastic-repository comes with spring-data-elastic. My elasticsearch server version is 5.2.2; and xpack is enabled.That is, it requires username and password to connect to it.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  data:
    elasticsearch:
      cluster-nodes: localhost:9200
      properties:
        shield:
          user: "elastic:changeme"
```

I couldn't find how to set username and password properly. I always get the following error:

```
2017-03-16 16:54:53.222  INFO 4005 --- [           main] org.elasticsearch.client.transport       : [Fixx] failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9200}, disconnecting...

org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [][127.0.0.1:9200][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness] request_id [0] timed out after [5006ms]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:698) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
```

Answer (score 0):

> ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]

This leads me to believe that you're using the 2.4.4 client to connect to ES 5.2.2. While a lot of API's are compatible a few are not (see [breaking changes in release notes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes.html)). I would upgrade your client library to 5.2, there is info here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed the version conflict. However, at this moment spring-data-elasticsaerch does not unfortunately support elasticsearch 5.x yet. So, upgrading only the elasticsearch client to 5.x does not solve the problem. I am going to give up spring-data-elasticsearch and use the bare client instead.

Answer (score 0):

you should use **x-pack-transport**.

1、update pom.xml

```
...
<!-- add the elasticsearch repo -->
<repository>
    <id>elasticsearch-releases</id>
    <url>https://artifacts.elastic.co/maven</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>x-pack-transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2</version>
</dependency>
...
```

2、Re instantiate **TransportClient**

```
@Bean
public TransportClient transportClient() throws UnknownHostException {
    return new PreBuiltXPackTransportClient(Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", "es-cluster")
            .put("xpack.security.user", "elastic:changeme")
            .build())
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
}
```

That's all.